# Displaying selected data in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have codes here that display all data in access database. Is it possible to only display specific or selected data from my database?

here is my code :

```
string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\SISC-STRONGHOLD\MIS!\wilbert.beltran\SEEDBucksDbase.accdb";
string query = "SELECT * From TableAcct";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.Columns["UserPassword"].Visible = false;

    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean selected data?  What's the criteria?  It sounds like you need a `WHERE` clause on your `SELECT` statement.  Such as `SELECT * FROM TableAcct WHERE Username='johndoe'`

Comment: @AdamPlocher - for example. I have employee table, when i type the lastname of that specific employee in a textbox then click a search button, it will display all other information related to that employee like his firstname, address, etc.

Comment: Is all that information stored in the TableAcct table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query for a last name (assuming the column in the table is called LastName), try this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE LastName='"+ textBox1.Text +"'";
```

Of course, you have to be careful of SQL Injection attacks.  I'm not familiar with using paramaterized queries in Access.

Is this a public form, or internal just for you (or trusted users)?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to write down `where` condition  in you query will do work for you,

Following is example of it

```
string query = "SELECT col1,col2 From TableAcct where col1=value";
```

This will fetch data that satisfy you condition and bind with the grid control.

And instead of `*` in select list give name of the columns you want to display.

for getting value form control like textbox

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE LastName='"+ textBox1.Text +"'";
```

**Note**- make use of sqlparameter to avoid SQLInjection , above is just an example.

Comment: for example. I have employee table, when i type the 'lastname' of that specific employee in a 'textbox' then click a search button, it will display all other information related to that employee like his firstname, address, etc in a datagridview :)

Comment: @bhert - you can do like this for it "string query = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE LastName='"+ textBox1.Text +"'";"

Answer (score 0):

string query = "SELECT (SelectedColumnNames) From TableAcct Where LastName=(LastName)";

INstead of Searching with a * in a Query enter the desired columns for ex:-
string query = "SELECT phno,address,FirstName From TableAcct where LastName ='"+txt1.text +"'";